# Anchor links scroll to incorrect position

Tags: html, wordpress, anchor

I'm struggling to make my anchor links work properly. Website is http://www.imprero.com and at the very top you see a link "Zobacz atrakcje" which should lead to a section below called "Produkty". Here already the scroll positions the window too much upward, since all two icon rows should be visible (according to div id="produkty"). Now this is the product list linked internally to sections of the page below. Only the first two position correctly, whereas all further are more or less wrong. In each product section there is a link "Lista atrakcji" which directs back to the product list. When I click the same icon link it many times directs me to a slightly different position. What the heck??? Any ideas? Would appreciate...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your fixed header is out of the document flow so it's height/position are not factored in to the scroll position of the browser. If you were to hide the header after clicking the anchor tag you would see that it does place you in the right position. This can be compensated for with a little CSS:

```
// Adjustment for anchor tag positioning with fixed header
:target:before
{
   content: "";
   display: block;
   height: 57px; //Height of header
   margin-top: -57px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, inserted your CSS at the end of my stylesheet and... didn't help. Have a look :( What did I wrong?

Comment: It looks like you made a typo when entering the CSS. I think you put it all on one line and the comment on height broke the margin-top rule. So my advice would be just to remove "//Height of header" and then try again.

The issue is on line 1395 of http://www.imprero.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/style.css

Comment: Didn't think the comment will break the rule. Anyway, still not good. Depending on the link, it moves to different positions and can't make it look good in every case :(

Comment: Well it looks like that is because the layout is different in each location. So the height of the div with data-node "58d13008b6de8" is 140px and the height of the div with data-node "5836c59051ea9" is 80px. This discrepancy (and some others) in your layout are causing the scroll position to be different for each anchor tag. The easiest way to see it is to take all the classes off of the div with data-node "5836c59051ea9" and replace them with all of the same classes from the other "fl-module fl-module-heading fl-node-58d13008b6de8 kontakt-inner-heading". Then both buttons behave the same.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are reffering to nodes which are not linked to in my issue. And don't understand why a different height of a div can influence the behavior of the anchor link scroll position. The fixed header is of course something to consider but that would be the case when each scroll to a target anchor would scroll to the same height, whereas each anchor directs to a different position of each targeted section. Furthermore, it targets to a different position using the same anchor, i.e. clicking a link with `#produkty` moves the scroll differently each time.

Comment: Lastly, typing the link manually in the address bar eg. [http://www.imprero.com/#sys](http://www.imprero.com/#sys) scrolls to the correct position, same with other links. The issue is with the buttons in this case. Why? Have no idea...

Comment: Then that means it has to be an issue with the _scrollToElementOnLinkClick function that is fired when you click on those buttons. You'll have to modify it to also compensate for the 57px height of your fixed header.